# How to scale and shift the coordinates of a Graphics object?

Tags: graphics, coordinate

I am trying to overlap two `Graphics` objects `g1` and `g2` with `Show`. However, I found that when the coordinates of each object is defined to quite different ranges, I need to "scale" and "shift" the coordinates of one object to get the desired look.

For example,

```
g1 = Graphics[{GrayLevel[0.8], Rectangle[{-2, -2}, {2, 2}]}];
g2 = Graphics[{{GrayLevel[0.5], Rectangle[{0, 0}, {1, 1}]}}];
Show[g1, AspectRatio -> 1, Axes -> True, ImageSize -> 230]
Show[g2, AspectRatio -> 1, Axes -> True, ImageSize -> 230]
Show[g1, g2, AspectRatio -> 1, Axes -> True, ImageSize -> 230]
```

The overlapped version of `g1` and `g2` looks like this
[image]

However, I would like to scale the coordinates of `g2` to make `g2` twice large and also shift its coordinates so the center can "roughly" coincide the center of `g1`. I say "roughly" because `g1` and `g2` may be some graphics not of a regular shape. The desired result will look like [image]

So how can I manipulate the coordinates of `g2` to adjust its relative position and size when `Show` with `g1`? Please avoid modifying the definition of `g1` and `g2` as they can be any `Graphics` copy-pasted over.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`Scale`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Scale.html)  on  `First @ g2` (which contains the graphics directives and primitives):

```
Show[g1, Graphics @ Scale[First @ g2, 2, {1, 1}], AspectRatio -> 1, 
 Axes -> True, ImageSize -> 230]
```

[image]

Alterantively, you can use combination of `Scale`  and [`Translate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Translate.html):

```
Show[g1, Graphics @ Translate[Scale[First @ g2, 2], -{1, 1}/2], 
 AspectRatio -> 1, Axes -> True, ImageSize -> 230]
```

or

```
Show[g1, Graphics@Translate[Scale[First@g2, 2, {0, 0}], -{1, 1}], 
 AspectRatio -> 1, Axes -> True, ImageSize -> 230]
```

> same picture

Comment: Thanks @kglr for the answer. Could you explain how the second argument of `Translate` is determined? Why it is `-{1, 1}/2` instead of `-{1, 1}`?

Comment: @nanjun, if you use `Scale[First@g2, 2, {0, 0}]` (with the third argument specifying the point that is kept fixed) you can use `-{1,1}` instead of `-{1,1}/2`) , that is, you can use  `Show[g1, Graphics@Translate[Scale[First@g2, 2, {0, 0}], -{1, 1}], 
 AspectRatio -> 1, Axes -> True, ImageSize -> 230]`

Comment: ... since `Scale[First@g2, 2]` fixes the center (`{1/2,1/2}`)  the origin of the rectangle is already shifted by `-{1/2,1/2}` before `Translate` is applied. (Compare `Show[g1, Graphics@Scale[First@g2, 2], AspectRatio -> 1, Axes -> True, 
 ImageSize -> 230]` and `Show[g1, Graphics@Scale[First@g2, 2, {0,0}], AspectRatio -> 1, Axes -> True, 
 ImageSize -> 230]`

Comment: Thank you @kglr for the explanation, which was very clear.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not saying that this is what you need for your problem, but sometimes when you want to superimpose graphics like this, you're looking for `Inset`:

```
Show[
 g1,
 Graphics@Inset[
   Show[g2, PlotRangePadding -> 0],
   {0, 0}, {Center, Center}, {2, 2}
   ],
 Axes -> True, ImageSize -> 230
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]